# Изменение размера шрифта в IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, шрифты, settings

Случайно увеличил размер шрифта на панелях навигации и забыл где это поменять обратно. Поиск по настройкам не помогает. Уже все вдоль и поперек облазил

Скрин моей идеи:
[image: Моя идея]

Скрин нормальной идеи
[image: Идея нормального человека]

Comment: Возможно изменили размер шрифта в настройках темы самого окружения `Ubuntu`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в Windows версии это находится настройках под

```
Appearance&Bevavior -> Appearance
```

и потом справа `override default font` , 
возможно это и в линукс версии.

советую использовать поиск в настройках, задаете слово, например  `font`, и настройки фильтруются.

Comment: спасибо !!! Помогло !

Answer (score 3):

Так-же, можно включить/отключить изменение шрифта в окне редактирования.
Нажмите комбинацию клавиш Ctrl+Shift+A, в строке поиска введите font size,
найдите переключатель Mouse: Change font size (Zoom) with Ctrl+Mouse Wheel

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]